# Replaying AWS step functions on edit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function with three states currently.

*Pass state -> Wait for 9 hours -> x Lambda Task.* - (a)

I want to update the state machine adding another task at the end, so effectively the machine would look like this:

*Pass state -> Wait for 9 hours -> x Lambda Task -> y Lambda task.* - (b)

Is there a way in which I can edit (a) to (b) and all the running executions will get updated with it ? 
Or the ideal way is to abort all the (a) executions  and supply the same data to run(b). If so, what would be the correct and possibly the easiest way to do this using SFN tools ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the step function [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_UpdateStateMachine.html)

> Running executions will continue to use the previous definition and roleArn

However, if you change your lambda function, step function (even if they were started before the lambda function was changed) will run the new lambda code when it reaches that state (assuming you are not using versioned ARN of lambda function in your state machine). You can change the lambda `x` to call lambda `y` while you are in migration phase which will ensure all running executions also run `y`.